# How CppUnit implements a test for an exception

Tags: c++, cppunit

I know that CppUnit makes it possible to test for an exception via:

```
CPPUNIT_ASSERT_THROW(expression, ExceptionType);
```

Can anybody explain how `CPPUNIT_ASSERT_THROW()` is implemented?

Answer (score 6):

Reporting of test failures in CppUnit is done via throwing of a custom exception type. We'll call that `CppUnitException` here for simplicity.

`CPPUNIT_ASSERT_THROW` is a macro that will expand to something that is essentially this:

```
try
{
   expression;
   throw CppUnitException("Expected expression to throw");
}
catch( const ExceptionType & e )
{
}
```

If `expression` throws (as we'd expect it to), we fall into the `catch` block which does nothing.

If `expression` does *not* throw, execution proceeds to the line of code that throws `CppUnitException` which will trigger a test failure.

Of course, the implementation of the `CPPUNIT_ASSERT_THROW` macro is actually a bit fancier so that line and file information is also reported, but that is the general gist of how it works.

Answer (score 3):

Edit: I've upvoted Michael Anderson's answer, since he is more specific about the exact code from CppUnit, while mine is a more general answer.

In pseudocode, it'll be something like this:

```
try
  {
  // Test code that should throw      
  }
catch(ExceptionType e)
  {
  // Correct exception - handle test success
  return; 
  }
catch(...)
  {
  // Wrong exception, handle test failure.
  return;
  }
// No exception, handle test failure.
return;
```